# Jquery datepicker only opens after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker in one of my forms. The only way it will appear when you click in the text field is if you refresh the page while you are editing the form. How can I get it to work any time you click in the field?

The coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
$(document).ready ->
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

I also tried the code from the calendars railscast:

```
jQuery ->
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

My form:

```
<%= f.text_field :deadline, id: "datepicker", placeholder: 'Deadline' %>
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Application.scss:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self 
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a turbolinks issue, use turbolinks:load instead.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
})
```

[See turbolinks docs](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads)

Comment: I get ```SyntaxError: [stdin]:4:46: reserved word 'function'```

Comment: Coffeescript issue on the previous comment. I got it to work by doing ```document.addEventListener "turbolinks:load", -> 
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'```